# Run docker on a Linux VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, docker

I am trying to run docker on a Linux VM on a Windows host machine.

VM is:

```
OS Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) x86_64 
Host VirtualBox 1.2
Kernel 4.19.0-16-amd64
```

Trying to launch sudo apt-get install docker-ce shows an error message:

It shows docker-ce has having some unmet depencdencies:

```
 docker-ce : Dipende: containerd.io (>= 1.4.1) ma non sta per essere installato
             Dipende: docker-ce-cli ma non sta per essere installato
             Dipende: libc6 (>= 2.32) ma la versione 2.28-10 sta per essere installata
             Raccomanda: docker-ce-rootless-extras ma non sta per essere installato
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you’re running Debian 10, try using the packaged version of Docker instead:

```
sudo apt install docker.io
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Restarted the system and it was installed properly.